# nebular toggle does not work in production mode

Tags: angular, toggle, nebular

I have a nb-toggle html element on my page. 
It works well in debug mode, but in production mode it look like this: 
[image]

Any suggestion what could cause this ?

[image]

this is locally run, looks very good. 
I use Angular 9 with nebular.

```
 <nb-toggle (checkedChange)="toggleTempHolder($event)" [(checked)]="service.tempholderChecked"
    class="input-group-sm" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0px;right:0px;"></nb-toggle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to create a css 
`nb-toggle .checked span{
    left: auto !important;
  }`

with this, it works as it should in production.